# obtaining isosurface boundary using contourslice?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have an issue. I currently have data for a 3D surface that describes a complicated trigonometric function f(rho1,rho2,beta) = 0. I obtained this data using isosurface as so:

```
[rho1,rho2,beta] = meshgrid(linspace(pi,0,100),linspace(0,pi,100),linspace(0,pi/2,100));

data = sin(rho1).*sin(rho2) + sin(beta).^3 + cos(2.*beta).*sin(beta).*cos(rho2) + sin(beta).^3.*cos(rho1).*cos(rho2).^2 + cos(2.*beta).*sin(beta).*cos(rho1).*cos(rho2) - cos(beta).^2.*sin(beta).*cos(rho1) + sin(beta).*cos(rho1).*sin(rho2).^2 + 2.*cos(beta).^2.*sin(rho1).*sin(rho2) + cos(beta).^2.*sin(beta).*cos(rho2).^2 + 2.*sin(beta).^2.*cos(rho2).*sin(rho1).*sin(rho2);

fv = isosurface(rho1,rho2,beta,data,0);
p = patch(fv);
isonormals(rho1,rho2,beta,data,p)
p.FaceColor = 'red';
p.EdgeColor = 'none';
daspect([1,1,1])
view(3); axis tight
camlight  
lighting gouraud
```

I am attempting to plot, in 3D, several "slices" of this surface. Currently I am using contourslice. I understand that this function interpolates contours based on the volumetric representation of my surface. I would like to have the contours lie exactly (or as close as numerically possible) to my volume's boundary. I currently have this:

```
hold on
s = contourslice(rho1, rho2, beta, data, [], [], [pi/4], 1, 'nearest'); 
view(3); 
grid on;
```

which is one z slice at pi/4 using the "nearest" interpolating method. this does not give me what I want.

any help is greatly appreciated...

[this image shows how the contour does not match my surface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEAZi.png)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find an answer of sorts by using the face/vertex data from the isosurface function and assembling these vectors into a loop that finds x,y pairs given a certain z value:

```
fv = isosurface(rho1,rho2,beta,data,0);
x=fv.vertices(:,1); y=fv.vertices(:,2); z=fv.vertices(:,3);
x_ring = [];
y_ring = [];
for i =1:length(z)
    if z(i)>pi/4-.01 && z(i)<pi/4+.01
        x_ring = [x_ring x(i)];
        y_ring = [y_ring y(i)];
    end
end
z_ring = ones(length(x_ring))*pi/4;
```

this code takes a range of values on either side of a certain z value and flattens these points onto a target z.

using the boundary command in matlab, we can find the set of points that lie on the boundary of the points collected from the loop. boundary returns the points and the area:

```
[k, area] = boundary(x_ring',y_ring');
hold on
plot3(x_ring(k)',y_ring(k)',z_ring(k)')
```

this should give us an approximate area within ~1% based off the "slice" width.

do you agree?